# Carrying out a simple dataframe subset with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following dataframe slice:

```
df = data.frame(locations = c("argentina","brazil","argentina","denmark"),
                score = 1:4,
                row.names = c("a091", "b231", "a234", "d154"))
df

     locations score
a091 argentina     1
b231    brazil     2
a234 argentina     3
d154   denmark     4

sorted = c("a234","d154","a091") #in my real task these strings are provided from an exogenous function

df2 = df[sorted,] #quick and simple subset using rownames
```

EDIT: Here I'm trying to subset AND order the data according to `sorted` - sorry that was not clear before. So the output, importantly, is:

```
     locations score
a234 argentina     1
d154   denmark     4
a091 argentina     3
```

And not as you would get from a simple subset operation:

```
     locations score
a091 argentina     1
a234 argentina     3
d154   denmark     4
```

I'd like to do the exactly same thing in dplyr. Here is an inelegant hack:

```
require(dplyr)    
dt = as_tibble(df)
rownames(dt) = rownames(df)

Warning message:
Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.

dt2 = dt[sorted,]
```

I'd like to do it properly, where the rownames are an index in the data table:

```
dt_proper = as_tibble(x = df,rownames = "index")
dt_proper2 = dt_proper %>% ?some_function(index, sorted)? #what would this be?

dt_proper2

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  index locations score
  <chr> <fct>     <int>
1 a091  argentina     1
2 d154  denmark       4
3 a234  argentina     3
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this using `filter` or some other dplyr function, and without some convoluted conversion to factor, re-order factor levels, etc.

Comment: check `tibble::rownames_to_column()`

Comment: it seems this allows one to convert back and forth between the latter two code chunks I've outlined above. Is it possible to do as I describe within the structure of the latter code chunk? I.e. ignoring row names - can the operation I've described be done using a column in a tibble?

Comment: If you want to do EXACTLY the same using `dplyr` why are you changing the dataset to `tibble`? Keep it as it is and do `df %>% filter(rownames(.) %in% sorted)`

Comment: I'm not changing it to tibble; I'm using tibble in general throughout my data processing; I just wanted to illustrate the operation I wanted to through the analogous operation with dataframe. The function you've specified will only filter; it won't re-arrange the rows unfortunately. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

you can simply use mutate and filter to get the row.names of your data frame into a index column and filter to the vector "sorted" and sort the data frame due to the vector "sorted":

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(index=row.names(.)) %>% filter(index %in% sorted)
df2 <- df2[order(match(df2[,"index"], sorted))]
```

Comment: Thanks; I don't think this returns the result I was looking for as it doesn't re-order the rows as the analogous operation would do in my first chunk above. I've added a target output to hopefully make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in the tidyverse (dplyr, tibble, etc.) are built around the concept (as far as I know), that rows only contain attributes (columns) and no row names / labels / indexes. So in order to sort columns, you have to introduce a new column containing the ranks of each row.

The way I would do it is to create another tibble containing your "sorting information" (sorting attribute, rank) and inner join it to your original tibble. Then I could order the rows by rank.

```
library(tidyverse)

# note that I've changed the third column's name to avoid confusion
df = tibble(
  locations = c("argentina","brazil","argentina","denmark"),
  score = 1:4,
  custom_id = c("a091", "b231", "a234", "d154")
  )

sorted_ids = c("a234","d154","a091")

sorting_info = tibble(
  custom_id = sorted_ids,
  rank = 1:length(sorted_ids)
  )

ordered_ids = df %>%
  inner_join(sorting_info) %>% 
  arrange(rank) %>%
  select(-rank)
```

Comment: If this is the only way to do it that's a shame - one might as well use the inelegant hack (`rownames(df) = custom_id >>> df[sorted_ids,]`) and live with it. I am surprised such a simple operation in base R is so convoluted in tidyverse!

Comment: Works the same with data frames, but at some point dplyr will probably convert them to tibble in the background anyway, thus removing row names, so keeping all data in columns is essential.

Comment: Actually, this might be the quickest re-creation: `dt_proper2 = dt_proper[match(sorted,dt_proper$index),]`

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out:

```
dt_proper2 = dt_proper[match(sorted,dt_proper$index),]
```

Seems to be shortest implementation of what `df[sorted,]` will do.